# Laravel Query Groupby Name and Sum of score => Output in javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have a table with scores in different gamerounds of players (teamnaam). Now I would show the total scores of the players. The sum of the scores works, but not the teamnaam of the players. Where do I make a mistake?

Controller:

```
$data['scores'] = DB::table('scoretest')->selectRaw("SUM(score) as total_score")
            ->groupBy('teamnaam')->orderBy('total_score', 'DESC')->get();

return response()->json($data);
```

Javascript:

```
success: function (result) {
    $.each(result.scores, function (key, value) {
        $("#scoreresultaat").append('<tr><td>' + value.teamnaam + '</td><td>' + value.total_score + '</td></tr>'); 
    });
}
```

Comment: You're not selecting `teamnaam`, so `value.teamnaam` is `null` (or `undefined`). Does it work if you change your code to `->selectRaw("teamnaam, SUM(score) as total_score")`?

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks! It doesn't work, I thought the same solution as you did, but it didn't work. (I've tried another time, but still not working).

Comment: Then you'll need to do some debugging on your end; `\Log::info($data['scores'])` in your Controller, see what is output to your logs, and/or `console.log(result)` in your Javascript file, etc etc. If `value.total_score` is working in your JS, but `value.teamnaam` is not, there's only so many reasons, the most obvious is that `$data['score'][X]['teamnaam']` (where `X` is 0-total number of rows returned) is not being set by your Query, but you'll need to figure out why. Also, please avoid *"doesn't work"* and *"didn't work"*; those statements are useless without more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The problem in your code

You are not selecting the field you try to reach. You will need to add it to your `select` clause, like this:

```
$data['scores'] = DB::table('scoretest')->selectRaw("teamnaam, SUM(score) as total_score")
            ->groupBy('teamnaam')->orderBy('total_score', 'DESC')->get();

return response()->json($data)
```

## How to troubleshoot

The query above should solve your problem, but it is possible that the behavior still differs from the one that you expect. These are troubleshoot steps:

- right-click on one of the score value, click on Inspect/Inspect Element so Dev Tools will open up and you will see your HTML, a `<tr>` and a `<td>` inside. If the `<td>` of your score is the second `<td>`, then your first `<td>` is not being displayed, possibly hidden by CSS or due to missing values (unnamed teams or teams). In this case you will need to fix this issue. If the `<td>` of the score is the first `<td>` inside the `<tr>`, then look further
- click on the Network tab of your Dev Tools, find the request that returned your data, click on it and click on the Response tab of your request panel, see what the response is. If `teamnaam` is defined in this response, then you have some Javascript that removes this `<td>` or other problematic code
- make sure that you send the request to the correct location and that the code is being run, possibly using temporary test codes that you write for this purpose